# Get all domain types with .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

How can I get all types in .net core (ASP.NET MVC 6) AppDomain? I found some examples:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/919

but they seems to be outdated.

Comment: For desktop CLR you do just like you did before. In CoreCLR there are no app domains. Please share more about the scenario that you try to achieve and we then can try to find a solution for you

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci is correct, there are no AppDomains in CoreCLR. Are you trying to get all the types of the available assemblies?